# changing the background color on update using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the background color of elements when they are updated.

When the response comes back from the server, I want to change the background color of the elements for a second or so, then change it back to the original.  I can change the background color, but I can't change it back in the same call.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    $("#" + objValue.id).parent().css('background-color','red');
});
//NEED TIMING EVENT FOR DELAY 
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    $("#" + objValue.id).parent().css('background-color','transparent');
});
```

The first loops works fine, but I can't get the other one to work.

I tried it this way:

```
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
     $("#" + objValue.id).parent.css('background-color','red').delay(1000).css('background-color','transparent');
});
```

and that didn't do anything either.

So I'm not really sure what the problem is.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    var $el = $("#" + objValue.id).parent().css('background-color','red');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $el.css('background-color', '');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wnntu/

Comment: That's it.  I tried it with a `setTimeout()`, but i wasn't using a variable.  thanks.

Comment: Joseph; this really works great -- I just implemented this personally instead of the queue / dequeue approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking more for `.css('background-color','')`. This will remove it from the element styles and therefore apply the last one up the chain. But not sure why transparent wouldn't work.

Update,

see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    $("#" + objValue.id).parent().css('background-color','red').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.delay()` only works with animation effects queues, or custom queues, and animation without jQuery UI doesn't work with colors...

Instead, you could use a `setTimeout()` call:

```
$.each(theArray,function(intIndex,objValue){
    var myObj = $("#" + objValue.id).parent().css('background-color','red');
    setTimeout(function() {
        myObj.css('background-color','transparent');
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention that he was animating between colors, just flipping them. He should be able to use delay to switch the color to empty

Comment: Correct, that was my point, that sticking a `delay()` between non-animated events won't work, unless you make a custom queue.

Comment: Thanks for explaining; I see what you're saying. The change would occur 'immediately' without a custom queue; I have demonstrated this functionality in a way that has worked for me in a separate answer. Is there a reason one would choose timeout over creating a custom queue?